# How to sort WordPress posts by a custom month field?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, meta, posts

I have WordPress posts that need to be sorted by a custom "month" field and a second filter of custom "day" field. Possible result:

```
- Dec 12
- Dec 10
- Nov 05
```

I have come up with this so far,

```
<?php
return array(
  "post_type" => "chronology",
  "post_status" => "publish",
  "posts_per_page" => 100,
  'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'month',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'day',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
  "order" => "DESC",
);
```

But it isn't working. Posts do appear, but they're not sorted according to the months. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Please define "isn't working".  That's a big statement.  Does your site load? Are there errors? Does the query run? What does it include / not include that you would like?  Also, in order to answer this, we need to actually know your meta field(s) and sample value(s).

Comment: Posts do appear, but they're not sorted according to the months.

Comment: The "day" values are 01 - 30
And the month values are "Jan Feb Mar" and so on.

Comment: So, there's (I believe) two problems: 1 - you've got NAMED month values, not numeric, so the sort would be wrong (apr would be first, not 4th), *and* 2 - I do not believe you can pass multiple meta values into the `order_by` parameter.  See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

simply add orderby date and order ASC .It will done the job for you.

```
<?php
    return array(
      "post_type" => "chronology",
      "post_status" => "publish",
      "posts_per_page" => 100,
      'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'month',
                'value' => '',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'day',
                'value' => '',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
      'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't work. This is because my dates aren't in the standard format. Need a custom query to sort this somehow,

Comment: Its actually in French, "Janvier, Frevrier, Mars, Avril, Mai" and so on.